# cast from sockaddr * to sockaddr_in * increases required alignment

Tags: c++, linux, networking, casting, clang

The compiler produces this warning when I'm working with some code which looks like -

```
....

for(p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    void *addr;
    std::string ipVer = "IPv0";

    if(p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
        ipVer                    = "IPv4";
        struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
        addr                     = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
    }

    else {
        ipVer                     = "IPv6";
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
        addr                      = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
    }
....
}
```

where `p = res` are of type `struct addrinfo` and the types producing warnings are `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6`. The warning comes from statements :

- `struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;`
- `struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;`

All I want to know is what is *causing* this warning and what *can I do* to correct it if this is not the proper way to do things. Could I use any of `static_cast` / `dynamic_cast` / `reinterpret_cast` here?

*The exact warning is* - `cast from 'struct sockaddr *' to 'struct sockaddr_in *' increases required alignment from 2 to 4`.

Comment: ??? `p` and `res` looks like having `struct addrinfo` type, isn't it? Anyway, the cast produced no warning on my platform (OSX, clang 700.1.81). Please precise your problem.

Comment: Oh ok you are using `-Wcast-align`, right?

Comment: To avoid it, you should use `memcpy` for example, breaking aliasing rules is UB.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès `-Wall -Weverything` here. However I don't understand how should I use memcpy here and how am I breaking aliasing? Looking forward to an answer :)

Comment: I would have say alignment, not aliasing.

Comment: If you use `reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(p)` the warning is not issued without using `#pragma`. This is actually the correct way to be casting in C++ anyway. C-style casts are discouraged.

Comment: @KurtStutsman why `reinterpret_cast` and why not the others ie. `static_cast`?

Comment: `static_cast<>` won't work in this case because `sockaddr_in` does not inherit from `sockaddr`. `reintrepret_cast<>` is for converting between unrelated types.

Comment: ah yes those structures don't have inheritence.

Comment: @KurtStutsman: Good catch. I added your suggestion to my answer, but feel free to add your own answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TLDR:** This warning doesn't indicate an error in your code, but you can avoid it by using a poper c++ `reinterpret_cast` (thanks to @Kurt Stutsman).

---

**Explanation:**

**Reason for the warning**:

- `sockaddr` consists of a unsigned short (usually 16 bit) and a char array, so its alignment requirement is 2.
- `sockaddr_in` contains (among other things) a `struct in_addr` which has an alignment requirement of 4 which in turn means `sockaddr_in` also must be aligned to a 4 Byte boundary.

For that reason, casting an arbitrary `sockaddr*` to an `sockaddr_in*`  changes the alignment requirement, and accessing the object via the new pointer would even violate aliasing rules and result in undefined behavior.

**Why you can ignore it**:

In your case, the object, `p->ai_addr` is pointing to, most likely is a `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` object anyway (as determined by checking `ai_family`) and so the operation is safe. However you compiler doesn't know that and produces a warning.

It is essentially the same thing as using a `static_cast` to cast a pointer to a base class to a pointer to a derived class - it is unsafe in the general case, but if you know the correct dynamic type extrinsically, it is well defined.

**Solution:**
<s>I don't know a clean way around this (other than suppress the warning), which is not unusual with warnings enabled by `-Weverything` . You could copy the object pointed to by `p->ai_addr` byte by byte to an object of the appropriate type, but then you could (most likely) no longer use `addr` the same way as before, as it would now point to a different (e.g. local) variable.</s>
`-Weverything` isn't something I would use for my usual builds anyway, because it adds far too much noise, but if you want to keep it, @Kurt Stutsman mentioned a good solution in the comments:

clang++ (g++ doesn't emit a warning in any case) doesn't emit a warning, if you use a `reinterpret_cast` instead of the c style cast (which you shouldn't use anyway), although both have (in this case) exactly the same functionality. Maybe because `reinterpret_cast` explicitly tells the compiler: *"Trust me, I know, what I'm doing"* .

---

On a side Note: In c++ code you don't need the `struct` keywords.

Answer (score 5):

Well `-Weverything` enables quite a lot of warnings some of them are known to throw unwanted warnings.

Here your code fires the `cast-align` warning, that says explicitely

> cast from ... to ... increases required alignment from ... to ...

And it is the case here because the alignement for `struct addr` is only 2 whereas it is 4 for `struct addr_in`.

But **you** (and the programmer for `getaddrinfo`...) know that the pointer `p->ai_addr` already points to an actual `struct addr_in`, so the cast is valid.

You can either:

- let the warning fire and ignore it - after all it is just a warning...
- silence it with `-Wno-cast-align` after `-Weverything`

I must admit that I seldom use `-Weverything` for that reason, and only use `-Wall`

---

Alternatively, if you know that you only use CLang, you can use [pragmas](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas) to explicetely turn the warning **only on those lines**:

```
for(p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    void *addr;
    std::string ipVer = "IPv0";

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-align"

    if(p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
        ipVer                    = "IPv4";
        struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
        addr                     = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
    }

    else {
        ipVer                     = "IPv6";
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
        addr                      = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
    }
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the memcpy version. I thnk this is needed for ARM which cannot have misalligned data.

I created a struct that contains just the first two fields (I only needed port)

```
struct sockaddr_in_header {
    sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
    in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
};
```

Then to get the port out, I used memcpy to move the data to the stack

```
struct sockaddr_in_header   sinh;
unsigned short              sin_port;

memcpy(&sinh, conn->local_sockaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in_header));
```

And return the port

```
sin_port = ntohs(sinh.sin_port);
```

This answer is really related to getting the port on Arm

[How do I cast sockaddr pointer to sockaddr_in on Arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706036/how-do-i-cast-sockaddr-pointer-to-sockaddr-in-on-arm?noredirect=1#comment82373628_47706036)

The powers that be think that to be the same question as this one, however I dont want to ignore warnings. Experience has taught me that is a bad idea.