# How do I cast sockaddr pointer to sockaddr_in on Arm

Tags: c, networking, arm, memory-alignment

I have the following code copied from elsewhere to get the client port from a server socket connection. On a 64bit Linux intel arch this compiles with out issues,

```
struct sockaddr        *sa;
struct sockaddr_in     *sin;
unsigned short          sin_port;

sa = conn->local_sockaddr;
sin = (struct sockaddr_in *) sa;
sin_port = ntohs(sin->sin_port);
```

In Arm its complaining that 'error: cast increases required alignment of target type' which seems reasonable.

I don't think I can ignore this.  Is there some way to tell GCC to fix the alignment so I can read the port?

Comment: See the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551879/cast-from-sockaddr-to-sockaddr-in-increases-required-alignment

Comment: See the "why you can ignore it" section of the accepted answer to the question linked by @aneeshjose. Try casting to void* first.

Comment: I don't think ignoring warnings is ever good advice for C code.

I added my final implementation based on memcpy to align the data to the linked question. I think you should re-evaluate if these are the same question. I added the tag ARM.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551879/cast-from-sockaddr-to-sockaddr-in-increases-required-alignment/47727876#47727876

The answer is not the best one to that OP but is relevant to this question.